# Should I use fallback: true or fallback: false in this scenario

Tags: next.js

I'm building my Blog, and am I trying to get getStaticPaths to work the best way possible. I'm planning to add articles to my CMS every day, the thing is if I use "fallback: false" the paths will only be generated at build time. I don't quite get if "fallback: true" is a good idea, will it affect SEO? Because if there would be a fallback component on the first render, I would assume it would affect SEO and web crawlers. What is the correct way of doing this, considering I will be adding articles to my CMS every day?

Answer (score 2):

The Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-true) state

> Web crawlers, such as Google, won't be served a fallback and instead the path will behave as in fallback: 'blocking'

This means that if a crawler requests the page, the returned HTML document will have the pre-rendered page. So from a SEO point of view, `fallback: true` is the same as `fallback: "blocking"`: They both have no negative effects on SEO, except maybe the long initial loading time (which is why I would have some kind of webhook on my CMS to request the page after publishing the post to have it pre-built before any crawler visits it).

If you'd have a lot of new articles/posts every day and don't use a CMS webhook or visit the page manually after publishing a new article, I'd pick `fallback: true` if it takes more than ~3-4 seconds to build the new page, and `"blocking"` otherwise.

But generally speaking, if you add a few articles every now and then, I wouldn't put in the effort to create a fallback page and just go with `"blocking"` as a simple HTTP request to the new page will already trigger the building and caching of the page, so no user will ever have to experience the fallback or blocking behavior.